# executando split() para formar uma list dentro de outra list

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, python-2.7

tenho a seguinte list:

```
[['a:/, b:/, w:/, g:/, f:/, d:/Downloads/Torrent/End, x:/files.2t, y:/files.1t'], ['d:/Dropbox/project/rato_bat'], ['data']]
```

porem gostaria que fosse uma list dentro de outra list poi isso fiz:

```
    for a in lldir:
        for b in a:
           b = b.split(', ')
```

seria possível fazer isso em uma linha e atribuir a uma variável?

Comment: Você quer produzir uma lista só a partir de todas as outras listas de dentro?

Comment: essa list já tem uma list dentro dela só que essa list esta sendo formada por uma única string que eu gostaria que fosse dividido em múltiplos itens usando o ", " (vírgula e espaço) da string.

Comment: voce está com  o mesmo tipo de pergutnas desde ontem - se ainda não estiver fazendo isso, sugiro fortemten que experimente um pouco com exemplos dos dados que voce tem em maos no prompt interativo do Python (como você está no Windows, use o `idle` )  - vocẽ está com um caso em que poderemos dar centenas de exemplinhos, e eles podem funcionar pontualmente, mas nada vai se tão claro pra você se eperimentar com isso no modo interativo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você quer algo como:

```
novo_conjunto = []
for a in lldir:
    nova_lista = [] 
    for b in a:
       nova_lista.append(b.split(', '))
    novo_conjunto.append(nova_lista)
a = novo_conjunto
```

Se quiser em uma linha só:

```
a = [[elemento.split()] for elemento in lista] for lista in a]
```

Se quiser uma única lista com todas as entradas de diretórios, de todas as sub-listas da primeira entrada:

```
diretorios = []
for lista in a:
    for elemento in lista:
        for diretorio in elemento.split(","):
            diretorio.append(diretorio.strip())
```